# SP2010 to SP2013 migration

Tags: 2013, migration, cumulative-update, service-pack

We are migrating from SP2010 to SP2013

At what stage do I need to install SP2013 SP1 and latest CU?

I mean should I install SP2013 SP1 and latest CU right after I install SP2013 binaries?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps, I would follow.

- Install SharePoint Binaries
- Install the Language packs
- Install the Latest CU
- Run the Config wizard and setup the farm.

You need to configure your farm before start of migration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So after installing SP binaries,SP1 and latest CU(in order),I run the Config wizard.After this,I install Language packs and their SP1 right?

Comment: oh you have LPs as well, check my answer now. I think now you will get the SharePoint 2013 with SP1 so no need to sperate installation of SP1 and same case with LPs

Comment: I've got Project Server 2013 also,So after installing SP binaries and before installing LPs,Project Server 2013 has to be installed right? Apologies for keep adding it